# Two Unknown Sony Corp Boards - Please identify

Tags: hardware, identify-this-computer, identify-this-card, sony

There are two Boards:

The first one has
Chips with the name "Sony 501 0C 185", "Sony 502 0J 043", "Sony 504 1B 002 504-3", "Sony 509 01 017 509-00", "Sony 501A00 0A-1" and more.
It has two numbers: 21569 and 1-581-258-12
It also  has the letter "B" next to the first number
[image: Top Side Of The First Board]
[image: Back Side Of The First Board]

The second Board has two (what I think is ceramic) ICs with the text "Sony 706 1G" and the other IC has "Sony 704 1G"
This board also has two numbers: "57850" and "1-581-255-12
It also has the letter "A" next to the "Sony Corp" text
[image: Top Side Of The Second Board]
[image: Back Side Of The Second Board]

Do feel free to ask for more info if you need more info to identify what the boards are and what they do.

Comment: Are these known to be computer-related or could they be anything Sony makes?  Certainly the top one is regular enough to be memory.  The white ceramic packages on the second board remind me of some processor chips.

Comment: I was also thinking it was some sort of memory board and processor, but I haven't a clue, but I do think that it is computer related

Comment: Do you know what standard the bus uses by any chance?

Comment: I rather doubt them being computer boards or even computer related. At best some (digital?/Analogue?) effects boards. Manufacturing technology looks much like mid 1970s A or AV equipment - which also fits the logo font used. n-nnn-nnn-nn is the part number structure used by Sony at that time for anything from radio to tape recorders.

Comment: It would make sense that they are maybe some type of audio equipment, as I had them in an old box with an old radio, but it doesn't look like it can connect to the radio

Comment: Sony did make a selection of table top calculators in the time frame theese cards where made, so it might be from one of them. This board (https://www.calcuseum.com/SCRAPBOOK/BITMAP/BONUS/30108/_SMD310972_XL.htm) from a Sony ICC1600E has a similar layout as one of the boards in the question, but the size differs.

Comment: They do share some chips, but the bus is different

Comment: @UncleBod those boards seem to use a solder mask, which the ones above don't. usually a good hit to distinguish between computer/digital electronics and A(V) PCB. The later being without for cost reason.

Comment: @another-dave I think the white ceramic ones could also be EPROMs with erase windows.